# Criterion for homogeneity

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and let $G=Aut(\Omega)$ be the **full** group of self-biholomorphisms of $\Omega$. Assume that there is $z\in \Omega$, such that the orbit of $z$ is somewhere dense, i. e. $\mathrm{int}~ \overline{G\cdot z}\ne\varnothing$. Does it follow that $\Omega$ is homogeneous, i.e. $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is a Lie group?  There might be domains that are homogeneous under the full group of self-biholomorphims but are not homogeneous under any Lie subgroup.  For example, I think that $\mathbb{C}^3$ minus the three axis lines is such a domain.

Comment: @RobertBryant $G$ is the full group of self-biholomorphisms. I guess I should add that $\Omega$ is bounded, things are usually more tangible under this assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: (21 May 2017)**  I have modified my answer to cover the case that the OP meant to ask, i.e., the assumption is that the *closure* of an orbit has nonempty interior.

Now that you have added the assumption of boundedness (and, I assume, connectedness, since, without it, the answer would clearly be 'no'), we can answer the question:  Yes, a connected, bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is homogeneous as long as there is any point $z\in\Omega$ such that $\mathrm{int}\bigl(\,\overline{G{\cdot}z}\,\bigr)$ is not empty.

The argument is as follows:  By a result of Kobayashi $\Omega$ is hyperbolic, and hence $G=\mathrm{Aut}(\Omega)$ is a Lie group that, in particular, preserves the Bergman metric on $\Omega$ (cf., Theorem 9.1 of S. Kobayashi, *Intrinsic distances, measures, and geometric function theory* Bulletin of the AMS **82** (1976), 357–416).

Suppose that $z\in \Omega$ is such that the closure of its orbit contains an $\epsilon$-ball $B_\epsilon(p)\subset \Omega$ for some positive $\epsilon$ (using, say, the Bergman metric to define distances).  Then the closure of this orbit contains $B_{\epsilon/2}(g{\cdot}z)$ whenever $g{\cdot}z \in B_{\epsilon/2}(p)$, and hence the closure of the orbit of $z$ contains $B_{\epsilon/2}(g{\cdot}z)$ for all $g\in G$.  Consequently, the closure of the orbit of $z$ is both open and closed and hence, by connectedness, is all of $\Omega$.

Now, let $p\in\Omega$ be arbitrary and let $g_k\in G$ be a sequence such that $g_k{\cdot}z$ is a Cauchy sequence that converges to $p$.  Since the maps $\phi_k:\Omega\to\Omega$ defined by $\phi_k(w) = g_k{\cdot}w$ are isometries of the Bergman metric, it follows that we can, by reducing to a subsequence, assume that,
not only does $\phi_k(z)$ converge to $p$, but the sequence $\phi_k'(z):T_z\Omega\to T_{\phi_k(z)}\Omega$ converges to an isometry $f:T_z\Omega\to T_p\Omega$.  It then follows by a standard argument using the path-connectedness of $\Omega$, that the sequence of Kähler isometries $\phi_k:\Omega\to\Omega$ converges on compact sets to a Kähler isometry $\phi_\infty:\Omega\to\Omega$.

It is easy to show that $\phi_\infty$ is a bijection, and, hence, it must belong to $G$.  Thus, $p$ is in the $G$-orbit of $z$.  Since $p$ was arbitrary, it follows that $G{\cdot}z = \Omega$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Could you please explain why if a sequence of automorphisms converge at a point and their derivatives converge, then they converge on compact sets? I assume this has to be some standard Cartan-ish result, so if you could point me to a reference, that would be great.

Comment: I will edit the question, so it matches your answer.

Comment: I guess another explanation is that if a sequence of isometries converges at a point, then it is a relatively compact set in compact-open topology by Arzela-Askoli theorem, and since holomorphic maps form a closed set in this topology we can choose a subsequence, which converge to a holomorphic isometry, that must be a bijection due to some kind of Schwartz Lemma, right?

Comment: @erz:  To get the convergence, I'm using the fact that the bi-holomorphisms of $\Omega$ are *isometries* of the Bergman metric.  It's a purely ODE fact that, if a sequence $\phi_k$ of Riemannian self-isometries of a connected Riemannian manifold has the property that $\phi_k(z)$ converges to $p$ one point while the derivatives $\phi_k':T_z\to T_{\phi_k(z)}$ converge to a linear map $f:T_z\to T_p$ (which is necessarily an isometry), then the isometries converge uniformly on compact sets to an isometry.  You don't need completeness of the metric for this.

Comment: Sorry, but again, could you please tell where to read this?

Comment: @erz:  Are you asking about isometries of the Bergman metric or are you asking about the Riemannian convergence theorem?  For the former, I think it's probably in an early paper of H. Cartan.  For the latter, this is basically an exercise, but I think you can find some version of it in one of Kobayashi's early papers on transformations preserving a parallelization, but I'll have to check for the exact reference.  I'll try to do this some time today.  The point is that the limiting isometry $\phi_\infty$ is the unique one satisfying $\phi_\infty(z)=p$ and $\phi'_\infty(z)=f$.

Comment: Yeah, I am asking about Riemannian convergence theorem. I am really unfamiliar with all this rigidity circle of results. Also, I get the impression that complex geometry to some extent coincides with the geometry of the Bergman metric (of the bounded domains at least). I wonder where can we get only using the complex structure...

Comment: @erz:  OK.  I had time to look this up.  The main paper (unfortunately, difficult to find) is S. Kobayashi, *Le groupe de transformations qui laissent invariant un parallélisme*, Colloque de Topologie, Ehresmann, Strasbourg, 1954, though you might also consult H. Chu & S. Kobayashi, *The automorphism group of a geometric structure*,TAMS **113** (1963), 141–150.  Look particularly at their Theorem G and the discussion paragraph that follows it.  The closedness of the $G$-orbit there implies exactly what I was describing, though you have to do a bit of translation.